# Create a search bar for hex values

Tags: vb.net, hex, arrays

My current code requires me to edit the search value while the project is still in VB. I have not been able to figure out how to code the input value to use a textbox for search. I would really like to be able to build this project and use it without having VB open. Below is my code:

```
Dim filePath As String = Me.TextBox1.Text 'The path for the file you want to search
    Dim fInfo As New FileInfo("C:\MyFile.File")
    Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
    Dim fStream As New FileStream("C:\MyFile.File", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
    Dim data As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))
    Dim pos As Integer = -1
    Dim searchItem As String = "b6" 'The hex values of what you want to search
    Dim searchItemAsInteger As Integer
    Dim locationsFound As New List(Of Integer)
    MessageBox.Show("Wait while I Scan?")
    br.Close()
    fStream.Close()
    Integer.TryParse(searchItem, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, searchItemAsInteger)

    For Each byteItem As Byte In data
        pos += 1
        If CInt(byteItem) = searchItemAsInteger Then
            locationsFound.Add(pos)
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(Hex(pos))
        End If
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Me.ListBox1.SetSelected(i, True)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Two points: "I would really like to be able to build this project and use it without having VB open" VB.net creates an .exe with each build in the debug folder. That you can run without Visual Studio. "have not been able to figure out how to code the input value to use a textbox for search" Input value of what? I'm confused by your goal and what your problem is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I dont have a search bar on my application. I am having to edit the  search value inside of my code, and debug in order to use it. Thus requiring me to keep VB open in order to enter and search the next value. The above code returns a list of offsets indicating my value in a file.

Comment: I'd like to use a textbox to search for "b6" instead of in my code

Comment: You're asking basically how to convert some text from a text box into a hex value for you to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a textbox named "txtHexValueToSearch" inside Form1. And then replaces the code that is commented:

```
' Dim searchItem As String = "b6" 'The hex values of what you want to search
Dim searchItem As String = Me.txtHexValueToSearch.Text 'The hex values of what you want to search
```